# how to bind click on year/Month/Week/Day in angular bootstrap calendar (mwl.calendar)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

I am using angular-bootstrap calendar. Here is the link
http://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink

I want to bind click on Year/Month/Day/Week button. I have read all the documentation but didn't get any clue even I tried to edit internal files but not able to do so.
[image]

Comment: try this  <label  ng-model="vm.calendarView" ng-click="vm.eventClicked()" uib-btn-radio="'year'">Year</label>

Comment: I tried on UI by inspecting element, not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but if you want to modify the calendar-view based on the button being clicked - this is what you need to do:
Define your buttons and specify the click-event (I called it `switchView`) like this:

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="switchView('day')">Day View </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="switchView('week')">Week View</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="switchView('month')">Month View</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="switchView('year')">Year View</button>
```

Then in your controller, you switch the view like this:

```
$scope.switchView = function (viewType){
  console.log('switchView:: viewType', viewType);
  //here I switch the calendar-view
  $scope.calendarView = viewType;
}
```

I hope this helps you and others. I used this technique in my application.